# Can I set KiTTY default codepage to UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1?

Tags: ssh, encoding, putty, utf-8, kitty

I always use UTF-8, but KiTTY always resets to ISO-8859-1 for new sessions, so I have to configure this every time. Can this be altered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open KiTTY
- go to *Window - Translation*
- configure the codepage
- go back to *Session*
- select `Default Session` from the list
- click *Save*