# How can I use UTF-8 on Linux from Windows 7 via PuTTY?

Tags: windows-7, putty, postgresql, utf-8, latin1

I use PuTTY on Windows 7 to access a Linux machine with Ubuntu 10.10. I think that Windows 7 is using Latin-1. But I need to use UTF-8 on the Linux machine and in a PostgreSQL database.

How can I do this with PuTTY?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set PuTTY to use UTF-8 from the configuration dialog when you connect. Go to Window -> Translation, and set *"Received data assumed to be in which character set"* to UTF-8.

Also check that your locale is something ending in `UTF-8` by running `locale` after connecting.

If it's not, run `locale -a` to see all the locales you have available. If there are no UTF-8 locales available, you need to configure your `/etc/locale.gen`, it's usually fairly well commented and it should be obvious what to add or uncomment. Then run `locale-gen` and check `locale -a` again to see the UTF-8 locale that was generated.

Something like `export LC_ALL="sv_SE.UTF-8"` ought to do the trick of actually setting the locale if and when it's generated.

Comment: @Jonas: That seems fine, UTF-8 locales all support the same symbols. `sv_SE.UTF-8` is just the Swedish locale, whereas `en_US.UTF-8` is the United States locale. In practice this only affects for example month names, date/time formatting and other minor stuff that varies by country.

Comment: Thanks, just changing the setting in PuTTY: Window > Translate as you mentioned was enough.

Comment: Related: [How to make the setting persistent](http://superuser.com/questions/264306/).

Answer (score 0):

The two basic factors are Window/Translation in putty and locale settings in Linux, as instructed here and many other places.

In addition, it may help in putty to set Connection/Data/Terminal-type string to "putty", and/or in Linux to export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1. These two are also mentioned multiple places.

But: you may still get blocks for certain characters because the default fonts like Courier and Lucida Console don't have all unicode chars. Download and install http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Download, and set putty to use it.

This last trick was necessary for me to get noping (recommended!) to show all graphic characters.