# byobu troubleshooting ubuntu 12.10 x64

Tags: ubuntu, putty, window, ubuntu-12.10, byobu

When I enter "byobu-enable" on my ec2 ubuntu 12.10 box, my putty ssh session goes insane.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

It looks like the windows is being duplicated and time is being cut off and wrapped around to a new line... which causes the screen to flash every second when the last (seconds) digit is updated.

Should I be enabling it using **sudo** or is there something else I am missing?

I tried removing scrollbars in putty in the hopes that my window was just being cut off by them but the exact same thing happens.

That green cursor in the middle is actually where whatever I'm typing is displayed, but every second my text gets bumped up to the line above... :S

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with Putty, not [Bybou](http://byobu.co).  You need to configure it to handle UTF8.

Putty -> config -> window -> translation -> choose utf in "Recieved data in ..."

See also:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/16912/ncurses-prompts-look-broken-in-putty-from-windows
- [How can I use UTF-8 on Linux from Windows 7 via PuTTY?](https://superuser.com/questions/264363/how-can-i-use-utf-8-on-linux-from-windows-7-via-putty)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859565/correct-putty-configuration-for-ubuntu-9-04

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*